# How to save the results from the MATLAB profiler

Tags: matlab, profiler

Is there a way to save the contents of profile so MATLAB can reopen the window later?
I'm not interested in saving as PDF. If someone has tips on how to get the save as html to actually work like the profile when it is open that would be useful too.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`profsave`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profsave.html) to save the results of the profiler as HTML that you can then open and navigate with your web browser.

```
profile on
% Run your code to profile
profile off 

% Path where you want to store the HTML profiler results
html_folder = 'path/to/html';
profsave(profile('info'), html_folder)
```